# How to format pandas dataframe in order to just keep one row per id?

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a pandas dataframe:

```
id feature1 feature feature3
A 1 0 0
A 0 1 0
B 0 1 0
B 1 0 0
B 0 0 1
C 0 0 1
```

So, this means this is a one hot encoded dataframe. I would like to get it now in a another format in order to just have one row per id:

```
id feature1 feature feature3
A 1 1 0
B 1 1 1
C 0 0 1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
out = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).max()
```

output:

```
  id  feature1  feature  feature3
0  A         1        1         0
1  B         1        1         1
2  C         0        0         1
```

Comment: If you are using ```id``` as an index like in OP then you do not need to include the ```as_index``` parameter